# Dockerfile has no effect

Tags: docker

Am starting with Docker and running into an issue. I want to enabled mod_rewrite in an apache-container and am using this docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-apache:
    image: php:7.2.1-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html:z
```

and this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.1-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
```

I run "docker build --no-cache ." with output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  90.16MB
Step 1/3 : FROM php:7.2.1-apache
 ---> f99d319c7004
Step 2/3 : RUN a2enmod rewrite
 ---> Running in 883573f39a39
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
Removing intermediate container 883573f39a39
 ---> 18c40ce865a6
Step 3/3 : RUN service apache2 restart
 ---> Running in b79bab530dc7
Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
.
Removing intermediate container b79bab530dc7
 ---> 8e2cfa7094f7
Successfully built 8e2cfa7094f7
```

Result: mod_rewrite not installed. When I log in to the console and manually run "a2enmod rewrite" all works fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't `image: php:7.2.1-apache` be `image: .` or wherever your Dockerfile is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker build --no-cache .` creates the docker image `<none>:<none>`.

Your compose-file references the base `image: php:7.2.1-apache`. You're basically preparing an image that you're not using.

You might want to use the `-t` argument in order to tag the image that you are building and then reference that image in the compose file. E.g:

```
docker build -t my-awesome-php-with-a2enmod --no-cache .
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-apache:
    image: my-awesome-php-with-a2enmod
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html:z
```

Comment: Awesome, that was the missing piece. Thanks!